# if statement grouped products reference woocommerce

Tags: php, filter, woocommerce, hook

In my functions.php file I have some remove_actions and add_filters that run for woocommerce but the problem is these functions run for all woocommerce product types.

I'd like to wrap a simple if statement around the hooks/filters I have to only run for grouped product pages the problem is I dont know how woocommerce refers to these pages heres what I have at the moment.

```
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

Heres what i'd like to do but I dont know the correct reference for $grouped_product.

```
 if ($grouped_product) {
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
 }
```

I have two add_filter and one remove action i'd like to append in my functions.php to only execute on grouped product pages I just need the correct reference in the first set of brackets in the second code block above.

Tried this code but it doesn't work..

```
if (is_product() and $product->is_type('grouped')) {
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
```

functions php file

```
 <?php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'parent-style';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() .       '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

//Remove cart options from under short description.

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

//Filter below adds new tab and returns cart options within tab.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_paym_product_tab' );

function woo_paym_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    // Adds the new tab

        $tabs['paym-plans'] = array( 'title' => __( 'Contract Deals', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 10, 'callback' => 'woo_paym_product_tab_content' );

    return $tabs;

}

function woo_paym_product_tab_content() {

    // The new tab content

        woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();

} 

//Filter below changes tab priority to display price plans first.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'sb_woo_move_description_tab', 98);

function sb_woo_move_description_tab($tabs) {



    $tabs['paym-plans']['priority'] = 10;

    $tabs['description']['priority'] = 20;

    $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 30;

    return $tabs;

}
?>
```

Comment: http://bryceadams.com/change-add-cart-text-woocommerce/ this guy does something similar but with add to cart text how can I copy his technique but with a remove action for grouped products only?

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem trick was to change it to a filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'filter_grouped_cart');  

function filter_grouped_cart(){
   global $post;
   if( function_exists('get_product') ){
   $product = get_product( $post->ID );
   if( $product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ){
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking $product->is_type('grouped') will not help here...

Please check if the code provides any help to you..

```
global $post; 
if( $post->post_parent != 0 ){ 
    echo 'is part of a group'; 
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to help me out :) so i pasted your code into my functions.php file in wordpress and searched for the string 'is part of a group' on the grouped product page but was unable to find it even in the page source. I can't understand why woocommerce have made this so difficult, any ideas?

Comment: Plugin author told me "You'd need to look at the global $post object and check the product type from there, only on is_singular('product') pages. "

Comment: found this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-product-type-check-is-it-external-for-further-action?replies=5 but when I copy and paste it into my functions.php site and add the remove action it just breaks my website?

Comment: http://bryceadams.com/change-add-cart-text-woocommerce/ maybe this type of thing may work?